# Is there any phrase, expression, or idiom for ‘is not any better’ or ‘is not very much better’?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Due to the authoritarian system, political development in this country is out of the question. Cultural development ————— .

I want a phrase for the blank to mean ‘is not any better’ or ‘is not very much/that better’.

Comment: "Not very much better" and "Not any better" are not the same thing!

Answer (score 3):

*no better (than)*

> Not any better than (someone or something); just as bad or inadequate as (someone or something).
>
> - With the way they treat the money of their employees and investors, these CEOs are ***no better*** than con artists, in my opinion. ([Freedict](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no+better+than))

> - If you turned to domestic politics, the news was ***no better***. ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/no-better))

Answer (score 0):

Provided a little rearrangement is tolerated, the adverb "likewise" fits perfectly.

- Due to the authoritarian system, political development in this country is out of the question, and likewise with cultural development.

Comment: I would have re-written it more naturally as _**and so is** cultural development_...

Comment: @fev Fine if you take into account only the being out of the question, but shouldn't we consider that this being out of the question for cultural development is,  in the same way, a consequence of the system being authoritarian? Does "so is"  necessarily include that cause? For instance, you can write this: "Due to the authoritarian system, political development in this country is out of the question, and so is cultural development, but for another reason.". I am not sure whether  the scope  include that much.

Answer (score 0):

A few options

> Due to the authoritarian system, political development in this country is out of the question. Cultural development ————— .

Cultural development is similarly (*non-viable* / *déclassé*).